# Change theme colors programmatically

Tags: android, colors, themes

I've got this Activity in my app that allows the user to select colors from a color picker:

[image]
[image]

I save the custom colors in SharedPreferences. What I'm trying to achieve now is to set those colors to ActionBar, TextViews, Buttons and other widget.

I've searched like a lot and couldn't find a way to edit the Theme programmatically.

Any ideas on how to achieve this without, ofcourse, insanely set background colors to like every single widget in my app?

EDIT:

This is why I'm trying to do:
Let's say that if the user doesn't like the setup of the colors of the default app theme (Orange ActionBar, Orange headers, Black Text, Orange and Grey buttons, etc) he then would use this feature that allows him to change the theme MAIN COLORS. For instance, he would just like the buttons to be blue, or the EditText to have a yellow background. I'm trying to create a feature that would allow the user to edit the app's theme.

This is what I've tried:
I've found [this library](https://github.com/AndroidAlliance/EdgeEffectOverride/blob/master/EdgeEffectOverride/src/main/java/uk/co/androidalliance/edgeeffectoverride/ContextWrapperEdgeEffect.java) that changes the color of the EndScroll Highlight. I was thinking I could use these ideas to achieve the thing described above, by then creating base classes for the widgets I'm using in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, views background colors can be changed on the fly.
If view has the gradient applied than use:

```
GradientDrawable sd = (GradientDrawable) (view.getCompoundDrawables())[0];
                    sd.setColor(Color.red);
                    sd.invalidateSelf();
```

or for the LayerDrawable

```
LayerDrawable layer = (LayerDrawable)(view.getBackground());
int randomColor = Color.rgb(redRandom.nextInt(255),greenRandom.nextInt(255),blueRandom.nextInt(255));                   
GradientDrawable sd = (GradientDrawable) (layer.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.tab_package_shape));
sd.setStroke(0, randomColor);
sd.setColor(randomColor);
sd.invalidateSelf();
```

Hope it will help you and provide the way to go further.